# use_2to3 is invalid WITH a downgraded setuptools<58.0

Tags: python, setuptools

I am facing an issue which has been discussed at length, and in many many forums, github issues, stack overflow questions, and so on.

To name a few:

[Error in anyjson setup command: use_2to3 is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72414481/error-in-anyjson-setup-command-use-2to3-is-invalid)
[error in suds-jurko setup command: use_2to3 is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642869/error-in-suds-jurko-setup-command-use-2to3-is-invalid)
[error in ibm_db setup command: use_2to3 is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69372639/error-in-ibm-db-setup-command-use-2to3-is-invalid)
[Problem with simpleeval installation:use _2to3 invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262518/problem-with-simpleeval-installationuse-2to3-invalid)
https://github.com/liftoff/pyminifier/issues/132
https://github.com/Thibauth/python-pushover/issues/42
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/76144

For me installing or downgrading setuptools to a version less than `setuptools<58.0` does not seem to fix the problem.

In order to test it I am creating a virtual environment using python3.7.9

```
(venv) ➜  headache git:(superbranch) ✗ python --version
Python 3.7.9

(venv) ➜  headache git:(superversion) ✗ pip --version
pip 23.1.2 from /local/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

The library in question is `vatnumber==1.2` and no, I am not able to change that version, so I need to solve the build problem without changing the version of that dependency.

My setup tools are:

```
(venv) ➜  headache git:(superversion) ✗ pip show setuptools
Name: setuptools
Version: 57.5.0
Summary: Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
Home-page: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
Author: Python Packaging Authority
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /local/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

And for completeness, this is the error

```
  Downloading vatnumber-1.2.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in vatnumber setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]
```

Running the same command using `-vvv` shows that when in a virtual environment a `pip` subprocess is initiated and `setuptools` is being upgraded to a version which does satisfy and internal `vatnumber` requirement, however it ignores the installed setup tool.

````
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Using pip 23.1.2 from /local/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Using cached setuptools-67.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
  Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
    Creating /tmp/pip-build-env-bswyzp5y/overlay/bin
    changing mode of /tmp/pip-build-env-bswyzp5y/overlay/bin/wheel to 775
  Successfully installed setuptools-67.7.2 wheel-0.40.0
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  error in vatnumber setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.```
````

I would like to ask, if anyone has stumbled upon a similar situation, or if anyone can provide any help in order to dig deeper into the issue and solve the build problem. I have no way of pinning the `setuptools` version in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same error (except it was for the anyjson package). I was able to fix it by running `pip install wheel`. I'm honestly not quite sure why it worked, but I think it has something to do with "Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully" by directly building the wheel instead.

https://pypi.org/project/wheel/

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to install the library with

`--no-build-isolation`

e.g.,

```
pip3 install setuptools==57.5.0 wheel
pip3 install -no-build-isolation --no-cache-dir -U vatnumber==1.2
```

[Build isolation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#build-isolation) is a feature of PEP518 in which the build process does not look for build-time dependencies (such as setuptools) in the local environment. The --no-build-isolation flag disables this feature so that the local setuptools installation is used for the build.